# Amortization table Visual C#

Tags: c#, arrays, listview

I am building an amortization table in Visual C#, with a list view to display the elements and with an array of strings to store them, I can put the numbers of pays, the amounts and interests, but I want to calculate the capital base on the rest of amounts minus interests.

How can I solve it?

```
public void Agregar(string aCuota, string aMontoCuota, string aInteres, string aCapital, string aMonto)
{
    string[] row = { aCuota, aMontoCuota, aInteres, aCapital, aMonto };

    itemsProcess = new ListViewItem(row);
    lvConsulta.Items.Add(itemsProcess);
}

//Agrega las consultas a las funciones establecidas en la clase
private void btnConsulta_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double tasaPeriodicaConsulta = 0.0;
    double cuotas = 0.0; ;
    double interes = 0.0; ;
    double capital = 0.0; ;

    //Plazos para pagar en meses
    int cantFilas = int.Parse(tbTiempo.Text);

    //Calculo de la tasa periodica
    tasaPeriodicaConsulta = calculo.TasaPeriodica(tbTasaAnual, tbTiempo);

    for (int i = 0; i <= cantFilas; i++)
    {
        if(i == 0)
        {
            cuotas = 0;
            interes = 0;
            capital = 0;
            saldoFinal = int.Parse(tbMontoConsulta.Text);
        }
        else
        {
             cuotas = calculo.MontoCuota(tbMontoConsulta, tbTiempo, tasaPeriodicaConsulta);
             interes = calculo.Interes(tbMontoConsulta, tasaPeriodicaConsulta);
             capital = calculo.Capital(cuotas, interes);
             saldoFinal = calculo.SaldoFinal(tbMontoConsulta, capital);
        }

        Agregar(i.ToString(), cuotas.ToString(), interes.ToString(), capital.ToString(), saldoFinal.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for a Formula? See for example [here](http://www.vertex42.com/ExcelArticles/amortization-calculation.html)